# Redirect 301 not work because of White spaces

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, whitespace

I have few Urls With White Spaces. i want to redirect these url to primary domain. But it does not work for me.

```
Redirect 301 "http://s41.domain.com/i/2014/3 - Johnny - Entertainment -   [Domain.com].mp3" http://domain.net
```

I think its issue with white space, Please suggest me how to fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

Use `RedirectMatch` instead to use regex and match multiple spaces with `\s`:

```
RedirectMatch 302 "(?i)(\x20|\s)-?(\x5B|\()Songspk\.cc(\x5D|\))\.mp3$" /
```

Also note that you cannot match domain name i.e. `http://...` in URI pattern.

To target a particular song:

```
RedirectMatch 302 "(?i)/indian2/entertainment2014/3(\x20|\s)+-(\x20|\s)+Johnny\s*Johnny(\x20|\s)+-(\x20|\s)+Entertainment(\x20|\s)+-?(\x5B|\()Songspk\.cc(\x5D|\))\.mp3$" /
```

Comment: I have used like that, but not working
RedirectMatch 301 "/indian2/entertainment2014/3\s*-\s*Johnny\s*Johnny\s*-\s*Entertainment\s*-[Domain.cc].mp3" http://domain.ch

Comment: Something like that http://so41.domain.com/indian2/entertainment2014/3%20-%20Johnny%20Johnny%20-%20Entertainment%20-%5BDomain.net%5D.mp3

Comment: At white space place %20

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70797/discussion-between-user1218948-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

URLs cannot contain whitespace. If you want to have whitespace in your url, you have to url-encode them.

A space character e.g. would turn into %20 - so if you correctly encode your url, this will work.

There are some tools online which you could use like: http://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Furthermore, leave the domain and protocol part out of the matching part of your statement.